# Access object properties from template to function - Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Simply, I have an array of objects, [images], that I display perfectly fine on Ng-repeat. When I click one div, I want to see the 'id' property of the particular image that was clicked on in the template.

Function in controller:

```
angular.forEach(value, function (value, key) {
    $scope.images.push({
        id: i,
        src: ("data:image/jpeg;base64," + value)
    });
    i = i + 1;
}

$scope.seeOne = function () {
    console.log(image.id);
}
```

My template:

```
<div id="galscrolldiv" ng-repeat="image in images">
    <div ng-click="seeOne()">
        <img ng-src="{{images[$index].src}}" width="100%" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Send the `image` as parameter from the view/template. Then you can access the image properties of the clicked image.

You've missed the `)` of `forEach`.

Controller:

```
angular.forEach(value, function (value, key) {
    $scope.images.push({
        id: i,
        src: ("data:image/jpeg;base64," + value)
    });
    i = i + 1;
});

// Get the parameter i.e. image that is clicked
$scope.seeOne = function (image) {
    console.log(image.id);
};
```

View/Template:

```
<div id="galscrolldiv" ng-repeat="image in images">
    <div ng-click="seeOne(image)">
    <!--                  ^^^^^-->
        <img ng-src="{{images[$index].src}}" width="100%" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Of course! I was overthinking it and forgetting this simple fact. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can also send the $index property from template

```
<div id="galscrolldiv" ng-repeat="image in images">
    <div ng-click="seeOne($index)">
    <!--                  ^^^^^-->
        <img ng-src="{{images[$index].src}}" width="100%" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Then inside the controller

```
$scope.seeOne = function (index) {
    console.log($scope.images[index].id);
};
```

But this may cause issue while using filter.
So in case of using filter avoid $index.